# REGEX how to extract the part after XYZ

Tags: regex

I'am quite new to regex and am trying to extract the 662050,89 from **X130503XYZ662050,89** after XYZ using a regex, I tried and wrote .

```
 [a-zA-Z](\d+|,\d)
```

I can only get 662050. How to get 662050,89 in regex? Thank you in advance

**Please note that the XYZ can be any letter and it can be anytimes line XYZ , XXYYZ ect**

Comment: How come you aren't getting "130503" with that regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using this reg exp (\d+,\d+). It will work just fine, if there are no float numbers within the X Y and before Z. Hope this will help.

**EDIT:**
Just keep in mind that the float number must be after the Z. Otherwise you may need to use [\d+,]*($|\z)

Comment: You are welcome. Just keep in mind that the float number must be after the Z. Otherwise you may need to use [\d+,]*($|\z)

Answer (score 3):

The regex can be simplier

```
XYZ(.*)
```

if XYZ can be anything but numbers, use `\D` token

```
\D{3}(.*)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try matching from the end of the input / word (JavaScript):

```
[0-9,]*(?:$|\z)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use this XYZ(.*) take the group 1 of the match for the 662050,89

or if you use this ([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+[|,]\d+) take the group 2 of the match for the 662050,89.

In the first case you only care for the numbers after the 'XYY', in the second case you care for both 'XYZ' and the numbers after it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex ...

```
/\w([\d\,]+)/
```